# preloaded data in html

Tags: javascript, html

What would be the best way to have preloaded data in html and then used with javascript. I do not want to use variables in javascript or save an ajax query.

It may be an XML data into a hidden div? .

Example:

```
1; Europe
2; Latin America

------------------

2, 1, Argentina
2, 2; Brazil
2, 3, Chile
1, 4, France
1, 5, Spain
1, 6; Italy
```

He would have to load the data into a select depending on the country you select. are much data and need to be fast, I prefer to have it preloaded.

**EDIT. Solution, based on the proposed solutions:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $_save_data = $("<div>");

    $("#xselect optgroup").appendTo($_save_data);

    $("#buttonAddA").click(function(){
        $("#xselect").empty();
        $_save_data.find("optgroup[id='a'] option").clone().appendTo("#xselect");
    });

    $("#buttonAddB").click(function(){
        $("#xselect").empty();
        $_save_data.find("optgroup[id='b'] option").clone().appendTo("#xselect");
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="buttonAddA">Add A</button>
<button id="buttonAddB">Add B</button>
<select id="xselect">
    <optgroup id="a">
        <option>a1</option>
        <option>a2</option>
        <option>a3</option>
        <option>a4</option>
        <option>a5</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="b">
        <option>b1</option>
        <option>b2</option>
        <option>b3</option>
        <option>b4</option>
        <option>b5</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="c">
        <option>c1</option>
        <option>c2</option>
        <option>c3</option>
        <option>c4</option>
        <option>c5</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you not want to use variables in javascript?

Comment: because I disagree with including javascript in the html file

Comment: what has that got to do with using variables?

Comment: If you don't want the Javascript in the same file, you can use it as an external script and load it through the script tag's src attribute. Why would you want to output html to parse into Javascript instead of simply outputting the data as JSON (Javascript)?

Comment: Working with ASP.NET MVC and I need to get the data into HTML and then working with javascript. In this form, I can not obtain the data with ajax. This is an example of my solution. JS will be in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the opposite thing in my project - I loaded full select, and then saved it's content with JavaScript and only inserted what I wanted. That way users without JavaScript (or users waiting for JavaScript to load) can use my form.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend doing it this way, but if you have no other options: you could have the following HTML:

```
<!-- header above this line -->
<div id="data" style="display:none">
  1; Europe
  2; Latin America

  ------------------

  2, 1, Argentina
  2, 2; Brazil
  2, 3, Chile
  1, 4, France
  1, 5, Spain
  1, 6; Italy
</div>
<!-- footer below this line -->
```

Then use script like the following to retrieve the information within the `data` div:

```
var dataDiv = document.getElementById('data');
var dataText = dataDiv.innerHTML;
// do something to parse dataText....
```

I think a better way to solve the problem would be to use your server-side language/framework (if you're using one) to inject a JavaScript object into a `script` element in the `<head>` of the page as it's being rendered before delivery.  This way you don't have to do any funky parsing like with my example above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the prohibition against just declaring a JS variable, but an alternative would be to build a JSON string on the server side and stick it into, say, the value attribute of a hidden form field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="some-id" value="{ abc: 123, ... }" />

and then...

<script type="text/javascript">
  // assuming you have some kind of JSON parser available
  var values = JSON.eval(document.getElementByID('some-id').value);

  // do something with values
</script>
```

MBO's solution is viable as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordan that JSON is the way to go, but there's a much easier way to use it than an input element with a massive JSON object as it's value: declare the JSON object in script tags:

```
var continents = {
1 : "Europe",
2 : "Latin America"
};
var countries = {
1 : {
1 : "France",
2 : "Spain"
},
2 : {
1 : "Brazil",
2 : "Argentina"
}
};
```

I'm not sure that I have the format right, but I think I'm close. To fetch the data, you could simply access the objects:

```
alert(continents[1]); // Europe
alert(countries[2][1]); // Brazil
```

Just make sure that the page has loaded before you try to access the data.

Comment: I agree entirely, but the OP said, "I do not want to use variables in javascript." I took that to mean that he doesn't want to declare a JS variable by generating it on the server side, as you do in your answer, but it's unclear why he wouldn't want that since, as you point out, it's the most straightforward solution.